# adding todays date mid sentence and return mm/dd/yyyy (manually not vba)

Tags: date, excel-formula

Not sure if I can post this here as it is not through a vba macro. I been searching but  can't seem to find a solution on here or google. I have a sentence in lets say A1 that I want to say:

```
*Productivity is based on past 4 weeks to today (7/27/2015 - 8/26/2015)
```

What I want to do is make it so I never have to change today's date "8/26/2015". I tried to to use & and looks like this

```
="*Productivity is based on past 4 weeks to today (7/27/2015 - " & TODAY() & ")"
```

problem is it returns as *Productivity is based on past 4 weeks to today (7/27/2015 - 42242)

How can I make 42242 return as a short date mm/dd/yyyy?

And is it even possible to make to make a formula for 7/27/2015 to go back 4 weeks to the monday of that week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the TEXT function:

```
="*Productivity is based on past 4 weeks to today (7/27/2015 - " & TEXT(TODAY(),"mm/dd/yyyy") & ")"
```

To go back four weeks (28 days) from today (alas, does not guarantee a particular day of week):

```
="Four weeks ago is " & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())-28),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Have not tested this extensively, but I believe this will get you back to the Monday of the week four weeks previous:

```
="Monday of week four weeks previous: " & TEXT(DATE(Year(today()),month(today()),day(today())-28-mod(today(),7)+2),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

The trick above is to use the MOD function to get an index into the current day of week, then offset that back to Monday...

Comment: Thanks it worked great. I combined the first and the last together to get what I wanted. I will just keep checking to see if it chooses the correct Monday every time.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. Might give it a vote if you're so persuaded :)